# How to getline() from specific line in a file? C++

Tags: c++

I've looked around a bit and have found no definitive answer on how to read a specific line of text from a file in C++. I have a text file with over 100,000 English words, each on its own line. I can't use arrays because they obviously won't hold that much data, and vectors take too long to store every word. How can I achieve this?

P.S. I found no duplicates of this question regarding C++

```
while (getline(words_file, word))
{
    my_vect.push_back(word);
}
```

EDIT:

A commenter below has helped me to realize that the only reason loading a file to a vector was taking so long was because I was debugging. Plainly running the .exe loads the file nearly instantaneously. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: How exactly do "vectors take too long"? O_o

Comment: I have to loop through over 100,000 words, storing each one. It took a little less than a minute when I tried it. Either way, I'd like to know how to read a specific line using ifstream.

Comment: If looping over 100,000 words took a minute you're doing something very very wrong. Code pleaaase.

Comment: How "specific" is the line at request? Do you know the line number of it? Are the words sorted alphabetically?

Comment: array can't hold a megabyte? What platform is that?

Comment: They are sorted alphabetically. I want to read a word, store it, do stuff, than read the n++ word from the file. Windows...

Comment: @vorbis5 One reason this may be slow is that `std::vector` probably has to re-allocate its internal memory several times to account for all of these elements that you are adding. Try initializing the vector with `my_vect(100000)` (constructor with the number of elements specified) *before* you append any words. I don't know precisely how much that will speed things up, but I'd be interested to know...

Comment: Store your words in a std::set<std::string> (std::vector should not be this slow).

Comment: @Chris thats a really good idea, ima try it.

Comment: @vorbis5: the best idea here may be to use a deque. See my answer for the code.

Comment: @David I'll check your answer in a few minutes...

Comment: Are you using a 20 year old computer or forget to turn the optimizer on. I just read in /usr/share/dict/words (250,000 words) into a deque in 1.6 seconds (note optimizer turned to -O3).

Comment: @Martin I'm not seeing an enormous difference between `std::vector` and `std::deque`.  In fact, `std::vector` is faster when I run the tests several times (doubtlessly because there are no reallocations after the first time); if you know the number of words in the file to start with, `std::vector` will be faster.  (But still not anywhere near as fast as using `ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' )` n times on the stream.

Comment: @James Kanze: Its slower using a vector (as you would expect because of the standard guarantees). But its still only 2 seconds to load 250,000 words.

Comment: My vector was in a class as a member and it was about 25 seconds without `.reserve(100000)`. It was about 7 or so seconds with reserve and 3 seconds using deque. I'm not a very good programmer as of yet so I'm not good at optimizing speed or anything. I'm running win 7 with 4g RAM.....

Comment: @vorbis5 You shouldn't have to optimize anything yourself.  Even without `reserve`, I'm seeing sub-second times to load almost 480000 words.  Without doing any "optimization" myself; I wrote the code (already posted) in a very straightforward manner.  I did use `istream_iterator`, introducing a separate class to do so.  But I can't imagine any great difference with a hand written loop.  The optimization we're talking about is that of the compiler.  (Very important, perhaps, is that debugging checks are turned off in the library.  They're on by default in VS, and are costly.)

Comment: WHOA!!!!!!!! Dude your absolutely genius. When I was debuging it I was getting around 4 seconds, but simply running the .exe cut the time down to what felt like nanoseconds! Thanks for this insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your words have no white-space (I assume they don't), you can use a more tricky non-getline solution using a `deque`!

```
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    deque<string> dictionary;

    cout << "Loading file..." << endl;
    ifstream myfile ("dict.txt");
    if ( myfile.is_open() ) {
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(myFile),
             istream_iterator<string>(),
             back_inserter<deque<string>>(dictionary));
        myfile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above reads the entire file into a string and then tokenizes the string based on the `std::stream` default (any whitespace - this is a **big** assumption on my part) which makes it slightly faster. This gets done in about 2-3 seconds with 100,000 words. I'm also using a `deque`, which is the best data structure (imo) for this particular scenario. When I use vectors, it takes around 20 seconds (not even close to your minute mark -- you must be doing something else that increases complexity).

To access the word at line 1:

```
cout << dictionary[0] << endl;
```

Hope this has been useful.

Comment: Is deque part of STL? It looks interesting.

Comment: Yes. Read the differences/similarities between `deque`, `vector`, and `list` here: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm

Comment: 1) why do you need the intermediate `bigstring` step, why not just use the `istream_iterator<string>` on the input file? 2) I guess that the better performance of `deque` over `vector` is because it's not required to be contiguous?

Comment: Reading the whole thing into a single string and then parsing that one word at a time seems like a big waste of time as the std::fstream is already buffered. You just end up copying the whole file round in memory a couple of more times than required. Trying to optimize stream usage like this is nearly always a waste of time as a pre-mature optimization. (time confirms: using using a dictionary of 250,000 words make a copy of the file in memory to parse slows down the app by 15%). PS using -O3 it gets done in 1.9 secs for your version and 1.6 secs without the bigstring.

Comment: @Martin: fixed :) - I overlooked the fact that they were both buffered, thanks for your input!

Comment: What could I do to get the code line by line?

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options, but none will automatically let you go to a specific line.  File systems don't track line numbers within files.

One way is to have fixed-width lines in the file.  Then read the appropriate amount of data based upon the line number you want and the number of bytes per line.

Another way is to loop, reading lines one a time until you get to the line that you want.

A third way would be to have a sort of index that you create at the beginning of the file to reference the location of each line.  This, of course, would require that you control the file format.

Answer (score 1):

I already mentioned this in a comment, but I wanted to give it a bit more visibility for anyone else who runs into this issue...

I think that the following code will take a long time to read from the file because `std::vector` probably has to re-allocate its internal memory several times to account for all of these elements that you are adding. This is an implementation detail, but if I understand correctly `std::vector` usually starts out small and increases its memory as necessary to accommodate new elements. This works fine when you're adding a handful of elements at a time, but is really inefficient when you're adding a thousand elements at once.

```
while (getline(words_file, word)) {
    my_vect.append(word); }
```

So, before running the loop above, try to initialize the vector with `my_vect(100000)` (constructor with the number of elements specified). This forces `std::vector` to allocate enough memory in advance so that it doesn't need to shuffle things around later.

Comment: My vector is part of a private class member. How do I `abc(100000)`? Resize or reserve?

Comment: @vorbis5 Use `abc(100000)` as the vector's constructor (i.e. `std::vector abc(100000)` or `abc = std::vector(100000)`)

Answer (score 1):

The question is exceedingly unclear.  How do you determine the specific
line?  If it is the nth line, simplest solution is just to call
`getline` n times, throwing out all but the last results; calling
`ignore` n-1 times might be slightly faster, but I suspect that if
you're always reading into the same string (rather than constructing a
new one each time), the difference in time won't be enormous.  If you
have some other criteria, and the file is really big (which from your
description it isn't) and sorted, you might try using a binary search,
seeking to the middle of the file, reading enough ahead to find the
start of the next line, then deciding the next step according to it's
value.  (I've used this to find relevant entries in log files.  But
we're talking about files which are several Gigabytes in size.)

If you're willing to use system dependent code, it might be advantageous
to memory map the file, then search for the nth occurance of a '\n'
(`std::find` n times).

ADDED: Just some quick benchmarks.  On my Linux box, getting the
100000th word from `/usr/share/dict/words` (479623 words, one per line,
on my machine), takes about

- 272 milliseconds, reading all words
  into an `std::vector`, then indexing,
- 256 milliseconds doing the same, but
  with `std::deque`,
- 30 milliseconds using `getline`, but
  just ignoring the results until the
  one I'm interested in,
- 20 milliseconds using
  `istream::ignore`, and
- 6 milliseconds using `mmap` and
  looping on `std::find`.

FWIW, the code in each case is:

For the std:: containers:

```
template<typename Container>
void Using<Container>::operator()()
{
    std::ifstream input( m_filename.c_str() );
    if ( !input )
        Gabi::ProgramManagement::fatal() << "Could not open " << m_filename;
    Container().swap( m_words );
    std::copy( std::istream_iterator<Line>( input ),
               std::istream_iterator<Line>(),
               std::back_inserter( m_words ) );
    if ( static_cast<int>( m_words.size() ) < m_target )
        Gabi::ProgramManagement::fatal() 
            << "Not enough words, had " << m_words.size()
            << ", wanted at least " << m_target;
    m_result = m_words[ m_target ];
}
```

For `getline` without saving:

```
void UsingReadAndIgnore::operator()()
{
    std::ifstream input( m_filename.c_str() );
    if ( !input )
        Gabi::ProgramManagement::fatal() << "Could not open " << m_filename;
    std::string dummy;
    for ( int count = m_target; count > 0; -- count )
        std::getline( input, dummy );
    std::getline( input, m_result );
}
```

For `ignore`:

```
void UsingIgnore::operator()()
{
    std::ifstream input( m_filename.c_str() );
    if ( !input )
        Gabi::ProgramManagement::fatal() << "Could not open " << m_filename;
    for ( int count = m_target; count > 0; -- count )
        input.ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' );
    std::getline( input, m_result );
}
```

And for `mmap`:

```
void UsingMMap::operator()()
{
    int input = ::open( m_filename.c_str(), O_RDONLY );
    if ( input < 0 )
        Gabi::ProgramManagement::fatal() << "Could not open " << m_filename;
    struct ::stat infos;
    if ( ::fstat( input, &infos ) != 0 )
        Gabi::ProgramManagement::fatal() << "Could not stat " << m_filename;
    char* base = (char*)::mmap( NULL, infos.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, input, 0 );
    if ( base == MAP_FAILED )
        Gabi::ProgramManagement::fatal() << "Could not mmap " << m_filename;
    char const* end = base + infos.st_size;
    char const* curr = base;
    char const* next = std::find( curr, end, '\n' );
    for ( int count = m_target; count > 0 && curr != end; -- count ) {
        curr = next + 1;
        next = std::find( curr, end, '\n' );
    }
    m_result = std::string( curr, next );
    ::munmap( base, infos.st_size );
}
```

In each case, the code is run

Comment: @vorbis5 Two quick notes, then: `Line` is a class I use a lot; it's just a wrapper around `std::string`, with a `>>` which uses `std::getline`.  (The production version also gets rid of any trailing `'\r'`---I'm constantly reading files under Unix which were written under Windows.  The version I used here doesn't have that.)  And `Gabi::ProgramManagement` is a namespace with a number of functions I regularly use for parsing `argv` and handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could seek to a specific position, but that requires that you know where the line starts. "A little less than a minute" for 100,000 words does sound slow to me.

Answer (score 0):

Read some data, count the newlines, throw away that data and read some more, count the newlines again... and repeat until you've read enough newlines to hit your target.

Also, as others have suggested, this is not a particularly efficient way of accessing data. You'd be well-served by making an index.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, there's this way:

```
for (int i = 1; getline(words_file, word); i++) {
    if (i == 7) {
        cout << word;
        break;
    }
}
```